# Genus of space curves given by the intersection of bivariate polynomial equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given two space curves defined by the equations 
$P_1(x_1,x_2)=0,\dots,P_{n-1}(x_{n-1},x_n)=0$ and $P_1(x_1,x_2)=0,\dots,P_{n}(x_{n},x_{n+1})=0$, respectively, is the genus of the former, say $g_1$, smaller than or equal to the genus of the latter,
say $g_2$? $P_k$ are polynomials. For example, if $g_2=0$, then the second curve admits a rational parametrization. Thus, also the first curve admits a rational parametrization and $g_1=0$. Conversely, if $g_1=0$, the second curve does not necessarily have a rational parametrization and, thus $g_2\ge0$. Is the inequality $g_1\le g_2$ always true?

More general question. Given a space curve in the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$, let me define a second curve by adding a variable $x_{n+1} $ and an additional polynomial constraint, is the genus of the second curve greater than or equal to the genus of the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgetting the variable $x_{n+1}$ defines a non-constant, so dominant,
morphism from one curve to the other, so yes.